# The multiplication of rank for finite projective modules

Tags: commutative-algebra

> Assuming all rings are commutative, suppose $M$ is finite projective module over $R$ of rank $m$ which is itself an $R'$-algebra that is as a module finite projective of rank $n$. How can we show that $M$ is of rank $mn$ over $R'$?

Where the rank means localized at any prime, the module is free of that rank.

It is straightforward that $M$ is finite projective but I have difficulty because even though primes of $R'$ lie below primes of $R$, $M$ localized at the two primes is different.

This is question 2 in section 7.9 of Jacobson's *Basic Algebra II*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me use a slightly different notation: We have $R' \to R \to M$, where $R$ is $R'$-projective of rank $s$ and $M$ is $R$-projective of rank $r$.

The previous exercise states that

> if $M$ is $R$-projective of rank $r$, then for any maximal ideal $m$ of $R$, $\dim_{R/m} M/mM = r$.

Since you already showed that $M$ is $R'$-projective, it suffices to show that for a maximal ideal $m$ of $R'$, $\dim _{R'/m} M/mM = sr$.

The extension $R'/m \to R/ mR$ is integral and $R'/m$ is a field.
Hence $R / mR$ is a finite product of Artinian local rings, and $M /mM$ is a module over this product. Write 
$$R/ mR \cong R_1 \times R_2 \times \cdots \times R_q.$$ 
Here, each $R_i$ is a localization of $R / mR$ at a maximal ideal, and $R_i$ is finite over $R'$.
We conclude that

> $\dim_{R'/mR'} R/mR = \sum \dim_{R'/mR'} R_i = s$.

Now, we apply the exercise to $R$ and $M$. As $M$ is $R$-projective, for each maximal ideal $n$ of $R$, $\dim_{R/n} M/ nM = r$.
Let $n_i$ be the maximal ideal which is the kernel of the morphism
$$
R \to R/ mR \cong R_1 \times R_2 \times \cdots \times R_q \to R_i.$$ 
Then $(R/mR)/ n_i(R/mR) \cong R/n_i R$, and $\dim_{R/{n_i}} M/{n_i}M = r$.

Lastly, we these numbers together. We have that 
$M/mM \cong \oplus (R/{n_i})^r$, and 
$$\dim_{R'/m} M/mM 
= \sum r \dim_{R'/m} R_i = r \sum \dim_{R'/m} R_i = r \dim_{R'/m} R/mR = rs.$$

Comment: I have a concern, how do we know M has a rank over R' at all. Sorry I haven't fully read the proof but I thought I couldn't apply the previous exercise because of this problem

Comment: I also don't see why R/mR is artinian?

Comment: After some thought I agree that you can use the exercise but I think it has to be more roundabout. Suppose $P'$ is a prime ideal of $R'$ we can localize everything at its complement. Then we get (localized) $M$ is $R$ finite projective rank $m$ and $R$ is $R'$ free of rank n and we need to show $M$ is rank $mn$ over $R'$ now a local ring. So now we can apply a dimension argument because there's no question about whether $M$ has a rank

Comment: Ah I see $R/mR$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: So following my comment above we can quotient by the maximal ideal of the now local ring to get to a situation where R is $s$ dimensional and M is rank $r$ and actually R is krull dimension zero as well but I don't think you use that.

Comment: I can follow until the line $M/mM \cong \oplus (R/n_i)^r$ can you elaborate on why that's true?

Comment: OK I see why. You map $M/mM$ to $\oplus M/n_iM$ and this is clearly injective and we can show $M/n_iM$ is $R_i$ free of rank $s$ (by usual arguments) then we need to show surjective but that follows by decomposing 1 in $R$ as the sum of the 1's in $R_i$ and using that to construct a preimage.